# Event is not occuring after adding the UIDatePicker on UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone

Please review the code

```
  -(IBAction)showDateSheet{
dateSheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Select Test Date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDateInLabel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
dateSheet.delegate=self;
//[dateSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 117, 320, 383)];
datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
CGRect pickerRect=datePicker.bounds;
pickerRect.origin.y=-100;
datePicker.bounds=pickerRect;
[dateSheet addSubview:datePicker];
[dateSheet showInView:self.view];
[dateSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320, 500)];

//[datePicker release];
//[dateSheet release];

   }
```

by using above code I am not able to click the cancel button , when i tap on cancel button nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is setting the bounds of `datePicker` like so:

```
CGRect pickerRect=datePicker.bounds;
pickerRect.origin.y=-100;
datePicker.bounds=pickerRect;
```

Essentially what you have done is shifted where the picker is drawn, but not where the picker's frame is. To see this more clearly set the picker's `clipsToBounds` property to `YES` and look at what you get. Even if you had not set `clipsToBounds`, you would not be able to interact with the section below.

What you actually want to do is set the frames origin down, not the bounds origin up, by a certain number of points. The working code would look something like this:

```
CGRect pickerRect=datePicker.frame;
pickerRect.origin.y+=110;
datePicker.frame=pickerRect;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the button on Action sheet something like this...

```
UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
closeButton.momentary = YES; 
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[dateSheet addSubview:closeButton];
[closeButton release];
```

this is to be done before calling `[dateSheet showInView:self.view];`

Then in the selector just write this..

```
[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]
```